# One node on multiple pages with tabbed navigation between fields

Tags: nodes, entities

I would like to create a Product content type with multiple fields and then showing those fields on seperate pages, let me give you an example:

I create a product type content named "Car" that has fields like "Mileage", "Color", "Year" and so on. When you open this content's page, you see the "Mileage" by default and you have a few tabs with "Color", "Year" that you can click to show those fields.

One possible solution I found is to use the Field Groups module, but I am looking for another one because the different sections will be heavy, lots of images and styling and I worry about that jQuery show, hide implementation will result in laggy, slow experience for the visitor.

Also it would be ideal if we could have a different URL for the sections like, car/mileage, car/color and so on.

Is there a rock solid solution for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy to implement so I think you're right not to want to include a whole module to do this. There's loads of ways to do this but here's one way I've done it recently:

In an overridden node.tpl.php, individually print out the fields you'd like tabbed in a wrapper. Within the wrapper you'll also need to print the links for each tab, with a href pointing to the ID of the item it's related to. Something like this:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#field1"><!-- Field Label --></a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="field1">
    <!-- Field Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then write some simple jQuery to show and hide the tabs on click:

```
$('div.product_tabs ul a').click(function () {
  $('div.tabs > div').hide().filter(this.hash).show();

  $('div.tabs ul a').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');

  return false;
}).filter(':first').click();
```

You could easily extend this so when the URL is visited with the fragment identifier on the end, the correct tab is shown.

Comment: Thank you, that's certainly a better solution for implement this than using a module, but this would still show and hide the sections with jQuery and I'm worried about laggy experience in browser during the show/hide, because the certain section will contain lots of images and styling probably, that's why I'm looking for another kind of solution.

Comment: I think you're going to struggle to do something without using some sort of Javascript.